# c# обновить combobox используя checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеются combobox и checkbox, а так же textbox, куда помещаются данные из combobox'a.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне при нажатии на checkbox обновлять\перевыбирать значение combobox? (грубо говоря, повторно вызвать выбор того же значения combobox'a)

Пробовал различные варианты, но срабатывает только единожды.

```
private void chkbx_codes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
  cb_eic.SelectedIndexChanged += cb_eic_SelectedIndexChanged;    
        }

private void chkbx_codes_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender; // приводим отправителя к элементу типа CheckBox
            if (checkBox.Checked == true)
            {
                chkbx_codes.Click += new EventHandler(cb_eic_SelectedIndexChanged);
            }
            else
            {
                chkbx_codes.Click += new EventHandler(cb_eic_SelectedIndexChanged);
            }
            cb_eic.Refresh();
        }

private void chkbx_codes_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender; // приводим отправителя к элементу типа CheckBox
            if (checkBox.Checked == true)
           {
               chkbx_codes.Click += new EventHandler(cb_eic_SelectedIndexChanged);
           }
            else
           {
               chkbx_codes.Click += new EventHandler(cb_eic_SelectedIndexChanged);
           }
            //cb_eic.Refresh();
           // cb_eic.SelectedIndexChanged += cb_eic_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }
        private void chkbx_codes_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            cb_eic.SelectedIndexChanged += cb_eic_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }
введите сюда код
```

При первом нажатии\включении\выключении checkbox'a срабатывает, при повторном ничего не происходит и при клике на текущее выбранное значение combobox'a ничего не происходит

P.S. Данные переключения мне нужны для того, чтобы в зависимости от выбранного параметра checkbox'a, основной combobox переключал вспомогательные combobox2 или combobox3

Comment: Когда я вижу вызов `Refresh`, я зверею... Вечно его лепят куда попало, как мартышка очки. Почему никто и никогда не читает документацию? Ведь в ней описано, что делает этот метод. PS: вам он совершенно не нужен.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov потому что я пробовал что угодно и всё подряд, чтобы получить результат. Поэтому и выложил все варианты.
Решения до сих пор не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

`cb_eic` - это что? Вот как угадать по этому набору символов, что скрывается под этим названием? Всегда давайте говорящие имена всем своим переменным (и контролам, соответственно, тоже).

---

> Как мне при нажатии на checkbox обновлять\перевыбирать значение combobox? (грубо говоря, повторно вызвать выбор того же значения combobox'a)

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса, то вот код, иллюстрирующий желаемое поведение:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ComboBox comboBox;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        TextBox textBox;

        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            comboBox = new ComboBox { Parent = this };
            checkBox = new CheckBox { Parent = this, Top = comboBox.Bottom + 20 };
            textBox = new TextBox { Parent = this, Top = checkBox.Bottom + 20 };

            comboBox.DataSource = (new string[] { "one", "two", "tre" });

            comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
            checkBox.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_CheckedChanged;
        }

        private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(comboBox, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Beep(); // просто для восприятия на слух
            textBox.Text = comboBox.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

В обработчике события `CheckedChanged` вызываем `SelectedIndexChanged`, передавая в него параметры.

---

Более правильным способом будет вынести код из обработчика события в отдельный метод. И в обоих местах вызывать именно этот метод.

```
private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessComboBox();
}

private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessComboBox();
}

private void ProcessComboBox()
{
    Console.Beep();
    textBox.Text = comboBox.Text;
}
```

Перед вызовом `ProcessComboBox()` и после него может иметься дополнительный код.

Метод может иметь параметры:

```
private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessComboBox("checkBox");
}

private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessComboBox("comboBox");
}

private void ProcessComboBox(string value)
{
    Console.Beep();
    textBox.Text = comboBox.Text + " " + value;
}
```

Comment: При первом нажатии срабатывает, при повторном нет (например, чекбокс выключен. Включил - сработало, выключаю - реакции нет). При повторном нажатии на тот же элемент комбобокса - он не попадает в текстбокс. Надо выбрать другой,потом обратно вернуться к этому.

Comment: @elmund0 - всё прекрасно работает. Если у вас есть проблема - _опишите её_. Конкретно, подробно, с примерами кода. И не в комментариях!